# cleos create account error: Failed with error: Assert Exception (10) prefix_matches(prefix, base58str): Signature has invalid prefix: SIG_K1_

Tags: cleos, accounts

I can recreate this issue every time on Ubuntu build and I have to be doing something wrong because I'm not seeing others describe it.

I build 1.0.6 (also happened with 1.0.5). I've deleted everything twice now and did new clones and build.

I run nodeos and then create wallet (default).
I unlock the wallet.
I create two keys.
I import those keys into my default wallet.
I try to create account with my two public keys and get the following error:

> "Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy
>   declared authorizations"

Based on some searching I do an import of the eosio private key. (I'm guessing this is where my error is coming in, but I don't really know what to do.)

I try to create the account again and get the

> "Failed with error: Assert Exception (10) prefix_matches(prefix,
>   base58str): Signature has invalid prefix: SIG_K1_..."

I have tried changing "SIG" to "TES" in signatures.hpp and rebuilding:

```
namespace fc { namespace crypto {
   namespace config {
      constexpr const char* signature_base_prefix = "SIG";
      constexpr const char* signature_prefix[] = {
         "K1",
         "R1"
      };
   };
```

Every time I get the same exact error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me see your cmd, you must strictly observe the following usage. "Usage: cleos create account [OPTIONS] creator name OwnerKey [ActiveKey]"